# In Italian, is the expression "... e mezza" used often to exaggerate a quality?

Tags: word-usage

Today I bumped into a friend of mine, an Italian native speaker, on the street I hadn't seen for quite a while. I'm pretty sure she said:

> Sarà **un'eternità e mezza** che non ti vedo!

In English, we use the expression "... and a half" to exaggerate a quality:

> I haven't seen you in **forever and a half**! == {**forever and a day**}

Does this (colloquial?) Italian expression work in a similar way? If so, what other nouns than "eternità" are commonly coupled with "... e mezza"?

Answer (score 5):

Ciao

Your translation is spot on. The English meaning is pretty much the same.

As far as I know, *un eternità e mezza* is not an established idiom, it's just personal quircky/fun use of the language. Although, Italian language greatly varies between regions and idioms greatly vary.

In short, *eternità* is not usually coupled with *e mezza*. It was a way to exaggerate and emphasise that she haven't seen you a while.

I am a native speaker :)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!